# Issue with logging in application

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I am trying to sort out the logging in app but some of the items I added to the code, get highlighted as an error. First of all, line 10, MySql is listed as an error, then line 32, 33, 34, 35 as well as 55.

Would you please assist me? Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient; 

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try

            {
                string myConnection = "datasource=s59.hekko.pl;port=3306;username=truex2_kuba;password=xxxx";
                SqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
                MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from databaase.users where uid='" + this.uid.Text + "' and pwd='" + this.pwd.Text + "' ;", myConn);
                MySqlDataReader myReader;
                myConnection.Open();
                myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
                int count = 0;
                while (myReader())
                {
                    count = count + 1;
                }
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Nazwa uzytkownika i haslo sa poprawne");


                }
                else if (count > 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Wpisano zle dane uzytkownika");

                }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Wpisano zle dane uzytkownika");
                MyConn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add MySql.Data reference to your project probably if line 10 fails.
Afer that do following changes:

```
 SqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
```

to

```
MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
```

then change

```
 myConnection.Open();
```

to

```
 myConn.Open();
```

then change

```
while (myReader())
```

to

```
 while (myReader.Read())
```

and finally

```
MyConn.Close();
```

to

```
 myConn.Close();
```

That should get you to go through build for start.

Comment: I have changed it but line 10 still fails, as well as 32, 33, 34.

Comment: After adding reference and changing these lines do you still have errors ?

Comment: When I added the reference, the issue is now gone. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have added a MySql reference in solution explorer and this had helped.